# Audio: background music in java JFRAME

Tags: java, file, audio, filestream

What is wrong in my codes? it have warnings about SUN API. it may remove in future release, it said..

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*; 

 import sun.audio.AudioData;
 import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
 import sun.audio.AudioStream;
 import sun.audio.ContinuousAudioDataStream;

AudioPlayer myBackgroundPlayer = AudioPlayer.player;
ContinuousAudioDataStream myLoop = null;
            //use a try block in case the file doesn't exist.
          try {

              AudioStream myBackgroundMusic = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("Audio/loop2.wav"));
              AudioData myData = myBackgroundMusic.getData();
              myLoop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(myData);
              }
              catch(Exception error) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid file!");}

              //play background music.
              myBackgroundPlayer.start(myLoop);
```

invalid file it said when i run this codes..

Comment: `Invalid file!` is your error message and doesn't help with an issue. Check out the type, message and stack trace of `error`.

Comment: Which line gives out that warning? And read the warning. It is crystal clear. The API you're calling is internal to the JVM implementation, not meant for Application developers as it may be removed without any notice.

Comment: @default locale, i see.. anyone from here can help me to play a background song?